# Python using text files as input and output

Tags: python

I am new to python although I am pretty farmiliar with Java and C, and I am attempting to create a chatbot that learns new words when you use them. I have the following Pseudo code to store words it doesn't know:

If word is not already in dictionary goto addword
...
addword
Take word and store it in the dictionary text file
Newline in the dictionary text file.

And then to read and output it I would (for now) just have it pick a random word from the list and insert it into the sentence string.

The trouble is, I have no idea what syntax to use in python for input and output with files.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be cool. Thanks.

edit: thanks I got it.
I used

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[x])
print(lines[y])
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am glad you got your answer; however your question is still needs to be modified to keep up with the guidelines of the community. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to know more. As of now, your question may get closed to prevent bad answers to appear. But, again, I am happy that you already found your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the synthax for opening a text file is as follows:

```
file_object = open('filename', 'mode')
```

Here, the mode can be either of the following:

- 'r' to read from the file, starting with the first line
- 'r+' to read from the file, starting with the first line, and be able
  to edit information
- 'a' to append to the end of the file (without modifying existing
  data)
- 'w' to clear the file and write in it, starting with the first line
- 'a+' or 'w+' to append, respectively clear and truncate the file, and be able to read from it

To go through a file line by line, you can use this command together with the 'with' keyword, as follows:

```
with open('file/path/and/name.txt', 'mode') as words_file:
    for line in words_file:
        # do something to the line
```

This ensures that at the end of the block beginning with 'with', the file is automatically closed.

---

In your particular case, you would need to open the file with the mode 'a+', then check for every line if it matches the given word, and if it doesn't, to append it to the end using the command 'write':

```
words_file.write(word_to_be_added)
```

Now for the second part, picking a random word, you would read the whole file into a string and then pick a random word from it, using something like:

```
with open('file/path/and/name.txt', 'r') as words_file:
    words = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in words_file)
random_word = random.choice(words)
```

Then you can just use random_word in your output sentence.

---

[This tutorial](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) should help for more details. In the future it might be best to just search for a tutorial related to what you're trying to do and try it yourself, and *then* post here about possible problems or questions you have about it.